# Firefox does not Show PDF File Extension on Download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, firefox, pdf, download

I'm using rails to send a pdf back to the client and in Firefox the file extension is not showing:

[image]

My rails code looks like this:

```
send_data(
      pdf,
      :type => "application/pdf",
      :disposition => "attachment; filename=transcript_#{Time.zone.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')}.pdf",
      # :filename => "transcript_#{Time.zone.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')}.pdf"
    )
```

I've been trying to set the file name with a combination of the `:filename` and `:disposition` key to display the correct filename in the browser. The `:filename` key doesn't seem to work in Firefox and the `:disposition` key gives me the picture above.

What do I need to change to get the pdf file extension to be shown in Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space (inside of the time format) is throwing off the file name. You need to surround the file name in quotes.

Try this:

```
:disposition => "attachment; filename=\"transcript_#{Time.zone.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')}.pdf\"",
                                      ^^                                                          ^^
```

This behavior is explained here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download.

The key point being that

> [The space] creates an ambiguity when parsing the header for the filename when the browser has to consider the possibility of internationalized filenames. As Internet Explorer does not have to worry about this, it will parse the filename until the end of the line. Mozilla will not.

Comment: neither chrome bother with this, i believe that mozilla should change this behavior

Answer (score 0):

this will definitely work

send_data pdf.render, filename: 'transcript_#{Time.zone.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')}.pdf', 
    type: 'application/pdf',
    disposition: "attachment"